# Expired Permesso di Soggiorno but valid student visa

Tags: canadian-citizens, schengen-visas

I am a Canadian Erasmus student in Italy and my permesso di soggiorno expires June 30th 2017, but my multi-entry student visa (D) does not expire until October of 2017. I want to stay in Italy for July and August to do some traveling within the country, but I am worried that this may be a problem.

Am I allowed to remain in Italy for these months with an expired permesso but a valid student visa? Would I have to leave when my permesso expires and re-enter as a tourist (being that I am allowed to be here for 90 days without a visa as a Canadian)?

Comment: Honestly I would ask at an official institution to be 100% sure. You don't want to overstay your Visa and then potentially be banned to enter the Schengen countries for the next few years just because someone on here misinterpreted the rules.

Comment: I have, only problem is I'm not really getting a straight answer from anyone unfortunately! I figured this might bring some type of clarity aha

Comment: Did you already ask the Canadian embassy in Italy?

Comment: No but I will give them a try! -- do you by chance have any idea what the answer might be though??

Comment: I don't know. I don't understand the rules either. In theory though it seems like you can just stay in the Schengen Area after the residence permit expires, until your student visa expires.

Comment: @szoszk the Canadian embassy in Italy is not the best source for information about Italian law.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem if your visa is still valid and you do not stay longer than 90 days total in 6 months period. Often different Italian authorities could give you different answers :) Immigrations officers in the airports in Italy don't care much when you leave the country as long as you have anything valid you should be fine. It could be a good idea to send an email to your consulate and have a printed answer with you.

Comment: The 90/180 restriction does not apply to people who hold a type D visa.